# numpy cannot call function library directly

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I'm using `python 2.7` on `ubuntu 16.04`. As described in the code below, I can't use any function from the `np.matlib`, but after I import, then it can be used. Is there any way to troubleshoot the problem? Thanks in advance!

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np 
>>> a = np.matlib.repmat([1,1],1,2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'matlib'
>>> import numpy.matlib as npm
>>> a = npm.repmat([1,1],1,2)
>>> print a
[[1 1 1 1]]
>>>
```

I think this is a library clash, and if so, how do I know which clashes against which?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Is that the actual order in which you executed those statements? I bet you didn't actually execute `import numpy.matlib as npm` before `a = np.matlib.repmat([1,1],1,2)`.

Comment: @user2357112 you are absolutely right. sorry. just update to reflect the change

Comment: This is just one of the sub packages that requires its own import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python import system does not automatically load submodules of a package when a package is imported. NumPy's `__init__.py` does automatically load most NumPy submodules on a plain `import numpy`, but `numpy.matlib` is not included.

Until some code somewhere in the program explicitly imports `numpy.matlib`, `numpy.matlib` will not exist, and its contents will not be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy.matlib as npm
```

This does not introduce the name `numpy.matlib` into the namespace; it only introduces the name `npm`. [Python 2.7 doc reference](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules).

If you want the module to be available through both `numpy.matlib` and `npm`, you can just define it that way, i.e. `npm = numpy.matlib`.